# Cross tabulation from lines to columns with Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with questions and answers for each respondent in rows and I would like to have all questions represented in a column. Some people don't answer all questions.

Eg. transforming this:

```
+---------+----------------+---------+
| User_ID | Question_Title | Answer  |
+---------+----------------+---------+
|       1 | Question One   | Answer1 |
|       1 | Question Two   | Answer2 |
|       1 | Question Three | Answer3 |
|       2 | Question One   | Answer4 |
|       2 | Question Two   | Answer5 |
|       3 | Question One   | Answer6 |
+---------+----------------+---------+
```

into that:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| User_Id | Question One | Question Two | Question Three |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
|       1 | Answer1      | Answer2      | Answer3        |
|       2 | Answer4      | Answer5      | --             |
|       3 | Answer6      | --           | --             |
+---------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I tried pivot tables but they don't seem to work with text values. Any clue?

Comment: @pnuts If I strip Answer from the data the table is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     =QUERY(A1:C7,"select A,max(C) group by A pivot B ")
```

Where A is the user id, C is the answer column and B is the questions column.
After you get the data, Use filter/pivot tables/another `QUERY`  to arrange them, if necessary.

Comment: Edit: Works if you replace the comma with a semicolon